# How to add an identity column to an existing database table which has large number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, identity

I have a database table which has ~ 40 000 000 rows. I want to add an identity column to this table. How to do it in a log-friendly manner?

When I do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE table_1
  ADD id INT IDENTITY
```

this just fills up the entire log space.

Is there any way to do it in a log-friendly manner? The database is on SQL Server 2008.

Thanks,
Mohan.

Comment: Is this MySQL, SQL Server, PostGres, Oracle?

Comment: disable log, add column, enable log.

Comment: Shouldn't that be an answer and not just a comment?

Comment: @Daniel, I see that there is no way to disable log in SQL Server 2008

Comment: @Mohan - there is no way of disabling the transaction log as that would violate ACID.

Comment: Can't disable the log, but you can change what operations are logged by modifying the recovery model. Look into changing the database recovery model to SIMPLE before the alter, then change it back to FULL after the alter is complete. Don't forget to get a transaction log backup before switching to simple, and a full or differential backup after changing back to full.

Comment: @beargle  - That still requires a way of breaking the task down into smaller transactions however. A simple `ALTER TABLE table_1 ADD id INT IDENTITY` will run as one transaction and even in simple mode the log will not be able to be truncated until the whole operation is complete.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.  I was able to increase the log space with the help of DB Admin and was able to create the identity column.

Answer (score 4):

The overall process will probably be a lot slower with more overall locking overhead but if you only care about transaction log size you could try the following.

1. Add a nullable integer non identity column (metadata only change).
2. Write code to update this with unique sequential integers in batches. This will reduce the size of each individual transaction and keep the log size down (assuming simple recovery model). My code below does this in batches of 100 hopefully you have an existing PK you can leverage to pick up where you left off rather than the repeated scans that will take increasingly long towards the end.
3. use `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN` to mark the column as `NOT NULL`. This will require the entire table to be locked and scanned to validate the change but not require much logging.
4. Use `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH` to make the column an identity column. This is a metadata only change.

Example Code Below

```
/*Set up test table with just one column*/

CREATE TABLE table_1 ( original_column INT )
INSERT  INTO table_1
        SELECT DISTINCT
                number
        FROM    master..spt_values



/*Step 1 */
ALTER TABLE table_1 ADD id INT NULL



/*Step 2 */
DECLARE @Counter INT = 0 ,
    @PrevCounter INT = -1

WHILE @PrevCounter <> @Counter 
    BEGIN
        SET @PrevCounter = @Counter;
        WITH    T AS ( SELECT TOP 100
                                * ,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY @@SPID )
                                + @Counter AS new_id
                       FROM     table_1
                       WHERE    id IS NULL
                     )
            UPDATE  T
            SET     id = new_id
        SET @Counter = @Counter + @@ROWCOUNT
    END


BEGIN TRY;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION ;
     /*Step 3 */
    ALTER TABLE table_1 ALTER COLUMN id INT NOT NULL

    /*Step 4 */
    DECLARE @TableScript NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Destination(
        original_column INT,
        id INT IDENTITY(' + CAST(@Counter + 1 AS VARCHAR) + ',1)
        )

        ALTER TABLE dbo.table_1 SWITCH TO dbo.Destination;
    '       

    EXEC(@TableScript)


    DROP TABLE table_1 ;

    EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Destination', N'table_1', 'OBJECT' ;


    COMMIT TRANSACTION ;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ;
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE() ;
END CATCH ;
```

Comment: Do you have a timeframe when you can put the dataqbase into single user mode? It is best to do this on prod in single user mode and with all users except the dba locked out.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of adding an identity column to a table with existing data:

1. Create a new table with identity, copy data to this new table then drop the existing table followed by renaming the temp table.
2. Create a new column with identity & drop the existing column

Reference  : http://cavemansblog.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/sql-how-to-add-an-identity-column-to-a-table-with-data/

Answer (score -1):

I just did this to my table that has over 2700 rows. Go to the design of the table, add the new column, set it to not allow nulls, set the column as an identity column in the column properties, and that should do it. I literally just did this less than 5 minutes ago and it worked for me. Please select as answer if this answers your question.

Comment: the person has 40 million rows, you have 2700, this solution will not work quickly