# How can I generate unique ID-s in existing db?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table named Food. I have 560 rows in it and the ID column is set to null for all rows. I want to generate random 10 length unique strings for the ID-s. 
How can I do that?

Comment: I think this post may work for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163275/how-to-add-an-identity-column-to-an-existing-database-table-which-has-large-numb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest is to just create a function to generate a random char and a unique index to guarantee uniqueness, if the insert fails due to duplicates, just try again.

```
CREATE FUNCTION random_char() RETURNS CHAR(1)
RETURN ELT(FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 62)), 
    'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
    'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M',
    'N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
    '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id_ux ON test (id);

UPDATE test 
SET id=CONCAT(random_char(), random_char(), random_char(), random_char(),
              random_char(), random_char(), random_char(), random_char(),
              random_char(), random_char())
WHERE id IS NULL;

DROP INDEX id_ux on test;
```